# usage of this in c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am new to c++.

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<string>
using namespace std;


class add{

public :
int a,b;
add();
add(int ,int);
add operator+(add);

};

add::add():a(0),b(0){};
add::add(int x,int y):a(x),b(y){};
add add::operator+(add z)
{
        add temp;
        temp.a=a+z.a;
        temp.b=b+z.b;
        return temp;
}

int main()
{
        add har(2,5),nad(3,4);
        add total;
        total=har+nad;
        cout<< total.a << " "<<total.b;
return 0;
}
```

This program is working fine now.But,earlier I have written

```
temp.a=this.a+z.a;
temp.b=this.b+z.b;
```

considering the call `total=har+nad;` is same as `total=har.operator+(nad);` and while compiling,an error was shown.

```
operover1.cpp: In member function ‘add add::operator+(add)’:
operover1.cpp:22:14: error: request for member ‘a’ in ‘this’, which is of non-class type ‘add* const’
operover1.cpp:23:14: error: request for member ‘b’ in ‘this’, which is of non-class type ‘add* const’
```

Why can't we use `this.a+z.a` here?

Some one please help me out.thanks.

Comment: Please always post the compiler error messages. I nearly gave you a bogus answer because of this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simple answer is that `this` is a pointer, so to dereference it you need to use `->` and not `.`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this as an alternative implementation:

```
add add::operator +(add z)
{
    z.a += a;
    z.b += b;
    return z;
}
```

You pass `z` in *by value*, (*i.e.* a copy), so you don't need to make yet another copy as `temp`, you can simply mutate this copy and return it *by value*.

Were you implementing `+=`, your implementation may look like this, passing in `z` by *const-reference*, but updating (and returning) `this`, which is, as the other answer says, *a pointer*. Not that you don't have to explicitly dereference `this` to modify members of a class:

```
add& add::operator +=(add const& z)
{
    a += z.a;
    b += z.b;
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: I have a feeling your first version might inhibit return value optimization.

Comment: I remember having an epic discussion about this once on SO, as I expected the return value copy to be elided. There is some explanation [in this blog](http://definedbehavior.blogspot.ch/2011/08/value-semantics-copy-elision.html). I could confirm it with some simple test code, compiled with gcc 4.7.3 on an x86_64.

Answer (score 0):

Member functions access the object on which they were called through an extra, *implicit* parameter named `this`. When we call a member function, `this` is *initialized*  with the address of the object on which the function was invoked.

The compiler passes the address of the object to the *implicit* `this` parameter in the member function.

Since `this` is a pointer you use the `->` operator.